# Unable to change Postgresql data directory with systemd service overrides on Ubuntu 22

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change the data directory that Postgres uses to look for its configuration files.

I have a fresh update of Ubuntu 22 and newly installed Postgresql@15.

In order to maintain version control over my Postgres configuration files, I've copied over the default configs to a new data directory in my server-configs repo, `/usr/local/apps/server-configs/configs/postgres/postgres_data/`.

Postgresql installs its service files to these paths: (*/lib, not /etc*):

```
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@15-main.service
```

Via `sudo systemctl edit postgresql` and `sudo systemctl edit postgresql@15-main.service`, I have added the following service environment variable assignment to both locations:

```
[Service]
Environment=
Environment=PGDATA=/usr/local/apps/server-configs/configs/postgres/postgres_data/
```

(*The double `Environment` declarations may be incorrect. In troubleshooting this, I read somewhere that they must be set to clear whatever was there before.*)

In turn this created 2 override files:

```
postgresql.service.d/override.conf
postgresql@15-main.service.d/override.conf
```

I then did both a daemon-reload and restarted Postgres, just for kicks.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Finally to check if the new data directory was picked up by Postgres, I connected to the database and checked via this method:

```
sudo -iu postgres
psql
postgres@logs:~$ psql

psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file               
-----------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

I've been reading lots of walk throughs that describe this as more or less the correct way to solve this. But no matter what I've been trying, the config file still points at the installed one and not the version in my `server-configs` repo.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: What the heck is /usr/local/apps/server-configs/configs/postgres/postgres_data ?  My Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have one of those.

Comment: /usr/local/ exists pretty much everywhere, linux, Unix, MacOS. server-configs is my configs repo.

Comment: Does the `postgresql` (or `pg_ctl`, or whatever `ExecStart` references) invocation in the service unit file contain the `-D` parameter? If so, I believe `PGDATA` will not be used at all.